# How can I beautify all files using Python script or some other ways?

Tags: python, c++, c, scripting

I have a lot of unindented C/C++ source files.I want to beautify all of them programmatically. How can I achieve that?

Comment: which IDE are you using? Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a python script that calls a C++ beautifier like Artistic Style.

http://astyle.sourceforge.net/

Here's how your python script would look:

```
# Collect all the files you need to beautify in "files"

#Loop through each C/C++ file
for file in files:
    command = "astyle " + file
    import subprocess
    process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
```

Example usage of Artistic Style is:

```
astyle example.cpp
```

or

```
astyle --style=ansi --indent=tab example.cpp
```